SurveySubject object relationship
I'm a little bit confused. Doc says that SurveySubject has ParentId field that

Unique identifier of the SurveyInvitation object or SurveyResponse object that is associated with this survey-object relationship.

Im able to find SurveyInvitation Object in Object Manager but not SurveyResponse.
What's wrong with my current org? How can we fix it?

As per this documentation,

Note You can’t define custom fields for the SurveyResponse object
using the Object Manager.


So, that's the reason why im not able to find it both in Object Manager and Schema Builder, correct?

@pincet, Yes. correct.
